# The last charachter gets red background and cannot write in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

[image: Image where the last char is red and as much as I type on keyboard does not change it.]

I think is a hotkey problem, because I pressed something by mistake and then happened like this, is there a way to reset the settings on my account and write like a normal person?
Sometimes it deletes the whole word and also a paragraph, it is very disturbing and I am not able to write.

Comment: ask the overleaf support.

Comment: Not really a LaTeX problem, but see if you enabled vim mode in the settings ore you pressed the "insert" button on your keyboard, overwriting your previous input in a typewriter-manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to change your Keybindings from "VIM" (that was accidentaly selected) to "none" in the settings in Overleaf.